# Show Child-pages of Specific Parent on any page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My website is build with alot of parents and childs.

I am currently using the follow function: https://gist.github.com/mprahweb/3c94d9c65b32ec9e3b2908305efd77d5

However it doesnt achieve what i want. I can only use it under the parent.

I want to be able to use a shortcode to list a child-pages for a specfic parent on any page (mainly the homepage)

The dream would be that i could have a shortcode like this:

[wpb_childpages_xxx] where xxx equals the parent page

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modified code:

```
function wpb_list_child_pages( $atts = array() ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'   => 0,
        'slug' => '',
    ), $atts );

    if ( $atts['slug'] ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $q = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_name = %s", $atts['slug'] );
        $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $q );

        if ( ! $post_id ) {
            return '';
        }
    } else {
        $post_id = absint( $atts['id'] );
    }

    $post = get_post( $post_id ); // WP_Post on success.
    $childpages = '';

    if ( $post && is_post_type_hierarchical( $post->post_type ) ) {
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( array(
            'child_of' => $post->ID,
            'title_li' => '',
            'echo'     => 0,
        ) );
    }

    if ( $childpages ) {
        $childpages = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
    }

    return $childpages;
}
add_shortcode( 'wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages' );
```

Using the Shortcode — use either `id` or `slug`, but if you specify a `slug`, the `id` will be ignored:

- To show child pages of the *current page*:
  `[wpb_childpages /]`
- To show child pages of *any pages*:

  1. With the post ID: `[wpb_childpages id="{POST_ID} /]`
     E.g. `[wpb_childpages id="123" /]`
  2. With the post slug: `[wpb_childpages slug="{SLUG} /]`
     E.g. `[wpb_childpages slug="home" /]`

Comment: Instead of using the id, could you use the page url/slug instead? That would make it easier from a editors perspective.

Comment: Cool, will test later. But why the dash in the end?

Comment: Nothing to worry about that `/`. I just like closing the Shortcode in a xhtml-style such as `<br />` instead of `<br>`. =) I mean, for self-enclosing Shortcodes.

Comment: just tested it. it doesnt work with the slug, only id.

Comment: same result.
i do it correct if my url is example.net/event
then i use [wpb_childpages slug="event"] right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Please try [this version of the code](https://pastebin.com/NYrk6U3e) and let me know what the result. That one is for debugging purpose, so please revert back to the code in my answer once you've done testing.

Comment: Im an idiot. The code works. I changed the slug between your replies :O

Comment: :D I'm glad to hear that!

Comment: @SallyCJ Would it be possible to add a expand/collapse function to your code? To toggle between showing/hiding all child pages.

Comment: Thank you @SallyCJ! How would I go about displaying only child pages, and not grandchild (and beyond) pages? Thanks again!