# Show Child post of Specific Parent on any page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to be able to use a shortcode to list a child post for a specfic parent on any page (custom post types mainly).

I found this: [Show Child-pages of Specific Parent on any page in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183161/show-child-pages-of-specific-parent-on-any-page-in-wordpress/50880216#50880216)

and it's perfect, but only for "`pages`" I think, it is not working for me with Custom Post Types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guillem,

You can keep use the code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183161/show-child-pages-of-specific-parent-on-any-page-in-wordpress/50880216#50880216).
Just add your custom post types in [wp_list_pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) function.

So, you will have:

```
$childpages = wp_list_pages( array(
 'child_of' => $post->ID,
 'title_li' => '',
 'post_type' => 'YOUR_CPT_SLUG',
 'echo'     => 0,
) );
```